# Excel VBA – Secure Timestamp

Tags: excel, vba, formula

Excel VBA – Secure Timestamp

I want to be able to create a secure timestamp on my Excel sheet. The VBA I am using will automatically add the current users user name, the time, and the date when a user puts information into column A. So if the users puts something into cell A1 then B1 automatically gets filled with their username and C1 gets filled with the time and date. The problem is that this method isn’t secure because the user could alter the information after it is automatically populated. I would like to add code to this VBA so it will lock all three cells after the information is populated.

I was planning on using the Protect Sheet feature and only allowing users to “Select unlocked cells” So if the VBA could auto lock the cells then the users would not be able to alter the information.

Any thoughts, suggestions, or help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rChange As Range

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Set rChange = Intersect(Target, Range("A:A"))
If Not rChange Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
 For Each rCell In rChange
    If rCell > "" Then
        rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = UserName()
        rCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Date & " " & Time()

    Else
        rCell.Offset(0, 1).Clear

    End If
 Next
 End If

 ExitHandler:
 Set rCell = Nothing
 Set rChange = Nothing
 Application.EnableEvents = True
 Exit Sub
 ErrHandler:
 MsgBox Err.Description
 Resume ExitHandler

 End Sub

 Public Function UserName()
 UserName = Environ$("UserName")
 End Function
```

Comment: Sugestion: replace `Date & " " & Time()` with `Now`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlock column A:A cells and protect sheet.

In your code, use `Me.Unprotect` before changing cells and `Me.Protect` after that.